# How to use complex variables in Azure DevOps pipelines

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines

I'm trying to compose a version in `variables` and then use it in `name`:

[image]

But it ends up like:

[image]

The reason I want it this way is to reuse `version` variable later to stamp assembly and tag a branch.

Is that possible at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found a better way to get a [build number](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/run-number?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) in later steps:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can update the pipeline name during the pipeline with a [logging command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/logging-commands?view=azure-devops):

```
- script: echo "##vso[build.updatebuildnumber]'$(version)'"
```

Comment: That fails with `##[error]TF209010: The build number format 0.1.4" contains invalid character(s), is too long, or ends with '.'` None of those statements seems to be true, but it fails ...

Comment: @Anthony see my update - add `'  '` to `$(version)` = `'$(version)'`, but you right in your answer, you can just give in `name` all the variables.